# Alt+Drag Does Not Focus Window

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, kde, plasma, kwin

When I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Mouse Left</kbd> to easily drag windows around, the target window does not focus. Is there a setting somewhere to make the alt+dragged window automatically focus without resorting to focus on hover? If I just click and drag the window title-bar or even the whitespace of the menu-bar, it focuses as I would expect.

Comment: Could you try with a new user account where all settings will be the default ones? For me, dragging windows leaves them focused.

Comment: @DKBose I created and logged into a brand new user, and the exact same thing: normal dragging focuses the window but alt+drag does not focus the window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The alt+drag behavior change be changed through System Settings (*systemsettings5*). Navigate to: Workspace > Window Management > Window Actions. Under the "Inner Window, Titlebar & Frame" section, change "Left button" from "Move" to "Activate, Raise & Move". And then "Apply".

[image: Window Actions][image]

Comment: You can also move windows just by clicking in the window's title bar and dragging. No need for `alt`. There's a gui for that in `System Settings` > `Appearance` > `Application Style` > `Applications tab` and then clicking on `Configure` to the right of the `Widget style` box. You'll get three choices in the dropdown next to `Windows' drag mode`